# Varnish rewrites location header

Tags: ssl, varnish, pound

My configuration is:
Internet -> Nginx as SSL-Offloader -> Varnish -> Nginx + PHP

When I send a redirect from PHP to https://foo.bar I see http://foo.bar.
It looks like Varnish rewrites Location header in response.
How can I fix it?

It's Ok in configuration without Varnish: 
Internet -> Nginx as SSL-Offloader -> Nginx + PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved :)
The problem was in balancer (Pound) config.
Internet -> **Pound** -> Nginx as SSL-Offloader -> Varnish -> Nginx + PHP

I set *RewriteLocation* to 0 and it solve the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Varnish does not support ssl. There is official explanation why: https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/phk/ssl.html

Comment: Yes, but I use SSL-Offloader (aka SSL Terminator, SSL Proxy). It allows me to cache SSL traffic.